# Google cloud app engine presistant socket.io connection

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, socket.io

I recently deployed a node.js app using socket io for realtime chat and was experiencing issues with socket connection initially. I fixed the issue by using the following app.yaml config

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

But now my question is how does this scale? Surely the single instance wont be able to handle a lot of traffic. I tried it without the manual scaling of the instances but I was still getting socket issues (Probably because two people who are talking are connected to different instances?).

How can I make sure that this scales properly while supporting the socket connections?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a good practice for your application to be agnostic in regards of which instance will serve the request.

However if this is not possible for your use case, you can check in the [App Engine Flexible documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity) that `Session affinity` is only guaranteed on a best-effort basis :

> Session affinity in App Engine is implemented on a best-effort basis. When developing your app, you should always assume that session affinity is not guaranteed.
>
> ...
>
> Because session affinity isn't guaranteed, you should only use it to
>   take advantage of the ability of socket.io and other libraries to fall
>   back on HTTP long polling in cases where the connection is broken. You
>   should never use session affinity to build stateful applications.

A possibility that you might want to explore is to [allocate more resources](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings) while maintining the service with only 1 instance, instead of horizontal scaling your application by spawning more instances.